# Card number verification during trial

Tags: recurly

I would like to offer a free trial of a subscription plan to users, and I would like to avoid users simply canceling the trial before the end and restarting again. So I would like to offer the trial only if the card is valid and hasn't been used before.

Is there a way through recurly to detect if a card number has been used before?

Additionally, what's the recommended way to verify cards through the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect if a card number has been used before. Perhaps validating using address or IP address could be a partial viable solution for limiting serial signups.

If you want to verify that the card is valid, Recurly will run a verification on the card once it's been [saved to an account](https://docs.recurly.com/transactions#verification).

If you want to verify that card *number* is valid, use [Recurly.js's](https://docs.recurly.com/js/#validation) `recurly.validate.cardNumber`, which validates a credit card number via luhn algorithm:

`recurly.validate.cardNumber('4111-1111-1111-1111');` --> `true`